# Connect to AWS-RDS MySQL from another aws Ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am pretty new to aws stack and trying to setup a simple node-mysql app.

Node is running on AWS EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 instance, and MySQL is running on AWS RDS instance.

I am trying to connect to MySQL from my Node client using popular MySQL connector  https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql but for some reason always getting 'Connection timeout'. Since node connection doesn't work, I tried to connect using a Telnet just to see if I at least can create any kind of connection.

```
telnet instance.12345.amazonaws.com 3306
```

but also unable to connect. Please note both of the connections e.g. though node app and through telnet do work when I try running them from my Windows localhost.

Things I've considered:

1. EC2 Ubuntu instance has Outbound rules to allow any kind of out
   request.
2. Running app as sudo.
3. RDS MySQL instance has inbound
   port 3306 open.
4. Installed MySQL client on my EC2 machine.

Basically have no idea on what exact step I've missed  during setup and just trying to poke anything possible, any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what error message did you get from the `telnet instance.12345.amazonaws.com 3306` command?

Comment: Show the actual security group rules. I assume the EC2 instance and the RDS instance are in the same VPC. You probably need to add a rule to the RDS instance's security group to allow inbound traffic from your EC2 instance's security group (or at least the EC2 server's private IP).

Comment: thanks guys, editing inbound rules on my RDS instance did the job!!